# Most common/well known translation of "Ice cream"

Tags: translation

I've heard two distinct translations of "Ice cream" in the past, “冰淇凌” and “冰激凌”. There also appears to be a third variant “冰淇淋” according to my input method. I used to think that there was another variant with the second character being pronounced as "qi" (without a tone), however after giving it some thought I think it's just a corruption of the second variant.

So, all in all, what is the most common/well known translation of ice cream in Chinese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

冰激凌 is the translation in Mainland China.

冰淇淋/甜筒 is used in Taiwan.

雪糕 is used in Hong Kong.

About 冰淇凌, it should be 冰激凌. Just the resemblance pronunciation, but it is a typo.

- 淋 = lín
- 凌 = líng
- 淇 = qí
- 激 = jī

Such as English,

- you = u
- what's up = wassup

Answer (score 1):

- 冰 is the translation of "ice" in 冰淇淋 and 冰激凌
- 淇淋 in 冰淇淋; 激凌 in 冰激凌 are both transliterations of "cream"

冰淇淋 and 冰激凌 are the same things, both mean "ice cream"

I lived in the Canton area and heard of 冰淇淋 more than half a century ago, while 冰激凌 is relatively new to me, I encounter it mainly in Mandarin-speaking regions publications. It was just a newer way to transliterate "ice cream" beside "冰淇淋"

Characters in transliterations are more flexible, therefore  冰淇淋, 冰激凌, 冰淇凌 and 冰激淋 would all be acceptable, but 冰淇淋 and 冰激凌 are still the two most common ones

We just call it 雪糕 in Hong Kong. Mainland Chinese would know 雪糕 is 冰淇淋/ 冰激凌 thanks to the popularity of Hong Kong media in the mainland

Answer (score 0):

It is an imported product, that is, a transliterated word. I cannot find out which one is official, or which one is better.

Regarding universality, I think both of your words are all common and well known. I believe 99% Chinese native speaker can understand 冰淇凌, 冰激凌 or 冰淇淋.

Answer (score 0):

I saw 冰基淋 before, but 冰淇淋 is more commonly seen, which could be the original translation. Also, Cambridge Dictionary translates it as 冰激凌 though.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/ice-cream